# Как в woocommerce вывести товары по произвольному полю

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Столкнулась с проблемой: есть товары с одинаковым значением произвольного поля. Нужно вывести на странице товара, товары с таким же произвольным полем.

Ничего подобного не нашла, это возможно? Например как выводят через шорткоды с помощью атрибутов?

`[product_attribute attribute="имя" filter="имя"]`

Можно ли вывести так же только через произвольное поле? Или через jquery? Неужели нет универсального кода?

---

Проблема решена с помощью WP_Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решила с помощью [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828655/woocommerce-get-products-by-attribute-query).

Пример кода:

```
// The query
$products = new WP_Query( array(
   'post_type'      => array('product'),
   'post_status'    => 'publish',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'meta_query'     => array( array(
        'key' => '_visibility',
        'value' => array('catalog', 'visible'),
        'compare' => 'IN',
    ) ),
   'tax_query'      => array( array(
        'taxonomy'        => 'pa_color',
        'field'           => 'slug',
        'terms'           =>  array('blue', 'red', 'green'),
        'operator'        => 'IN',
    ) )
) );
```

Comment: Если никто не ответтил, а вы нашли решениие, просто даёте самоответ. Предыдущий ваш ответ был не более чем комментарий, это имелось ввиду.